# Universal extension using relative Ext sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, exact-sequence

Let $\pi: X \to B$ be an elliptic surface with a section $\sigma$.
Assume that $\pi, X, B$ are all smooth and that $X,B$ are projective.

Let $E_{r_1,d_1}$ be a vector bundle of rank $r_1$ and degree $d_1$ on $X\times_B X$ such that $0<r_1<r$.

Let $E_{r_2,d_2}$ be a vector bundle of rank $r_2$ and degree $d_2$ on $X$ such that $E_{r_2,d_2}|_{\ell}$ is stable and such that $\operatorname{det}E_{r_2,d_2}|_{\ell} \cong \mathcal O(d_2\sigma) $ for every fiber $\ell$.

I want to understand two claims:

1. by Atiyah's classification of stable vector bundles over elliptic curves, $\mathcal L:=\operatorname{Ext}^1_{p_X}(E_{r_2,d_2},E_{r_1,d_1} ) $ is a line bundle on X. Here $p_X$ is the projection $X\times_BX \to X$.
2. There is a universal extension
   $0\to E_{r_1,d_1}\to E_{r,d}\to E_{r_2,d_2} \otimes p_{X}^*(\mathcal L)\to 0$.

I am mostly interested in the claim 2. The only reference I found on the relative Ext was [this paper](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/272332/1-s2.0-S0021869300X03626/1-s2.0-0021869383901394/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEFgaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJIMEYCIQCjgdeXwlyZ7834Vb%2FcEgymF%2FQNsCKB9ixf1OCGEMTS0wIhAJwrmuLR%2FORYop7irocRjwhwlSP7cKu1EN%2F9y3qqqx0pKrsFCMH%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEQBRoMMDU5MDAzNTQ2ODY1IgyGnMXFqoskS9Ewj9EqjwWQOXDQbfBcOnTDew4YA%2BZAggMOmU%2FUfWVgNi0qowgHOVwILIsUtSwxAMnVLOQ1Surbb%2F0HF55HEe4RV14hCrLyrPrnL4CbMxV3U9DPHm0riIP1zNJS29NJx7XB1RuETko3ubuy%2FYYnMuGdUhHc6RZZY4QzQqsLpmX%2FgCknqkKrtWsJ%2FxLmNfRd36ok9CxDrZFUgLmMZXttXx9wVA7An2XAt%2BahV5iC%2FL%2BWTcMHcdnjizA3S5809iXN%2BtSMNz2wlf3sddDjHEVN%2BVb4vXMCGByBcmt6QyLVdcLTerZsPikLv4Vhy8nRryfAqsqA1x%2FiM3kPSK4P%2BMXdEC19J3ZkdX2KTPdDaOI1G3QeMAEuMVmxfatdKZkR%2F4eaao5lVi%2F6fEcqBkUkqekHaB9t4FIMcv8KHTwk%2B8EO3AdNkLgduCqzktEiwyEMmDZXfNpSoUxJDnD7sbaNPW3mFPsDCs9Gm9G8HbvILg4kj7d1ERGtjCVcZ564hIiLW6gdXGtBqmbd%2BxIhuNhOH3CWs1GoX8P88YSTcNHNn4Ud%2FH7nsleoXT3zb%2B4S5v9XQtkihNVsgMe0LU8EZPgdIvXvmB942aPaG%2FNknj8WrULRpDjkdhHcPpXv0eWLtX6ovya%2Bb6zPPz7zRx6uRbY99LvvSovbmImotZv%2FCs2ftAYByCE9dI1yopRa7jzyBoiowdvhGRHo0iv97XeQKll8O4ADJ0vbBu66GMPpHPzhj2JaThE5OAYPMiQbgAaKy1wCuxI1Yi%2FDutODwmIDLcc%2F2Tkw2en1bmsP9WL%2FH2PGm9K9xdMKGwL%2Fdv12yzAbsl7GikT2M2l97hwDeXHToOZx6HCsjXZZb2bDdvzJj0tKVGY%2B8mtiNIlfEE6dMMeZgaUGOrABaEa2gzndoGzbCP8IsSPgoIqMFpzt49rwnOebB5xcSDCgXxcrHnkilzZkWvfKKvDfjQ2yUSUY6o66oJSIM1qNGgCfi%2BpCLypRwDMflz0fDbW73F4wxAiYF1QlqMmZj%2BjXGaonCfZfv3K61z4ega5TTdbPOWO93H5KLUUChTLVAMJb15%2BwbEeSWAQYSCj2PwEC76hanTSCiAUhZs8eazZnGteDSNaZN%2FADkH6ampEOLrk%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20230701T165746Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTY5UKRTIMK%2F20230701%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=9fae252ca9fba94b862c96b91c208f34b47c79d43e0f548995673ca4609180f9&hash=98fadfb4f1ff5334fb4ed641a8b6826228351599cd88c7822e2519d802237b1d&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=0021869383901394&tid=spdf-20c5b60f-7eef-406e-ae7b-541f2dfe2182&sid=de7f8a5c1fd7c1416689a1a05249d344b7b0gxrqb&type=client&tsoh=d3d3LnNjaWVuY2VkaXJlY3QuY29t&ua=1e03550757515c5e590004&rr=7e00309fccc02675&cc=de) from H. Lange. but I couldn't obtain any hints for the universal extension.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just note that
\begin{align*}
p_{X*}\mathcal{E}\mathit{xt}^1(E_{r_2,d_2} \otimes p_X^*(\mathcal{L}), E_{r_1,d_1}) &\cong
p_{X*}(\mathcal{E}\mathit{xt}^1(E_{r_2,d_2}, E_{r_1,d_1})  \otimes p_X^*(\mathcal{L}^\vee)) \\
& \cong
p_{X*}\mathcal{E}\mathit{xt}^1(E_{r_2,d_2}, E_{r_1,d_1}) \otimes \mathcal{L}^\vee \\
& \cong
\mathcal{H}\mathit{om}(\mathcal{L}, p_{X*}\mathcal{E}\mathit{xt}^1(E_{r_2,d_2}, E_{r_1,d_1})) \\
& \cong 
\mathcal{H}\mathit{om}(\mathcal{L}, \mathcal{L}).
\end{align*}
The right-hand side has a natural global section (corresponding to the identity morphism), it gives a global section of the left-hand side, hence the required extension class.